# Cannot install MS Office 2010 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, microsoft-office-2010, language-pack

I have formated my notebook and installed Windows 7 in Portuguese language.

When I try to install MS Office 2010 I receive a dialog box saying that office does not support the language of Windows 7.

Can't I install MS Office 2010 on my notebook on English version?
Do I need some kind of English pack installed to support it?

Comment: Could you please provide the exact error message, with any error codes that are shown?

Comment: @Stephen: It will take some time to post the error message, I'm not with my notebook right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Windows 7 Ultimate, you can download the language pack and see if that will help: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/language-packs

Comment: I do installed Windows 7 ultimate. I'll check if it helps and I'll let you know.